# Filter string from inside an array

Tags: php

I tried this:-

```
function sum_array($arr_sum){   
        $string= "";

        $length= count($arr_sum);
        $sum= NULL;
        if(is_string($arr_sum)){
                echo "You cannot use string";
            }else{      
                for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++){
                $sum = $sum + $arr_sum[$i];
            }
                echo " The Sum is ". $sum;
                }
    }
    $array_summation=["string",12.6,25.2,10,12];
    sum_array($array_summation);
```

I want to know what should i do if i want only integer or float value inside an array, and if string come inside array it gives error that no string wanted or something like that

Comment: You should accept an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function sum_array($arr_sum){   
        $sum = 0;
        foreach($arr_sum as $value){
            if(!is_numeric($value)){
                echo 'Array Contain non numeric data';
                exit;
            }
            $sum += $value;
        }
        echo 'The sum is '.$sum;
    }

    $array_summation=["string",12.6,25.2,10,12];
    sum_array($array_summation);
```

Comment: Thanks Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to get the type of each value present in the array -

```
$type = array_map('gettype', $array_summation);
if (!empty($type) && in_array('string', $type) {
  echo "You can't use string.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Worked for me

Comment: This only checks the type of the first element in the array and ignores the rest. Also you're also missing quotes around `'gettype'`.

Comment: @jitendrapurohit What about if someone has an object or another array as a value? That's why I'm using `return is_float($n) || is_int($n);` in my answer.

Comment: OP has given an example for an array, and this works for validating it.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a built-in [array_sum](http://php.net/array_sum) function, which ignores non-numeric strings.

```
$arr = [1,2,'3','apple'];
var_dump(array_sum($arr)); // int(6)
```

Or if you really need them to produce an error you can use [array_map](http://php.net/array_map):

```
function sum_array($arr) {
    if (array_sum(array_map('is_numeric', $arr)) !== count($arr)) {
        echo "You cannot use string";
        return;
    }
    echo array_sum($arr);
}
sum_array([1,2,'3','apple']); // You cannot use string
sum_array([1,2,'3','5.2']); // 11.2
```

Or if you want to make sure that all values in the array are either floats or integers, and not numeric strings, you can do:

```
function is_non_string_number($n) {
    return is_float($n) || is_int($n);
}
function sum_array($arr) {
    if (array_sum(array_map('is_non_string_number', $arr)) !== count($arr)) {
        echo "You cannot use string";
        return;
    }
    echo array_sum($arr);
}
sum_array([1,2,'3','apple']); // You cannot use string
sum_array([1,2,'3','5.2']); // You cannot use string
sum_array([1,2,3]); // 6
```

Comment: Thanks Worked for me

Comment: Note: This will allow [numeric strings](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php), such as `"3.5"`. If you want to disallow that and only allow integers or floats, let me know and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Yes please specify that case also

Comment: @MughalGee Updated.